# Grub, error: attempt to read or write outside of partition

Tags: linux, debian

мне потребовалось увеличить размер диска на сервере, но через parted я по ошибке изменил размер на 200мб вместо 200гб, теперь система загружается только так, есть ли возможность через Grub восстановить раздел?

Система OSnova(Debian 10)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто изменить обратно на 200гб? Главное не форматировать

Comment: Да, там есть данные которые нужно сохранить

Comment: Ну и, разумеется, не через grub, а загрузившись с какого-нибудь LiveCD/LiveUSB в котором будет parted или аналог

Comment: можно какой-нибудь гайд как это правильно сделать на VMware

Comment: я загрузился с live, захожу в parted, пишу resizepart, указываю 200GB и пишет ошибку 
Error: Can't have overlapping partitions.

Comment: Ну тут уже вам виднее, что у вас за дичь с разделами творится

Comment: Измените размер не на 200GB, а на тот, что был до вашего упраженения с `parted`.